# Post username with uppercase name

Tags: php, authentication

I'm creating a simple chat app that shows the user's name. At the moment it outputs `steve` rather than `Steve`

For this line;

`$text = "{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']} <strong>|</strong> {$timestamp} <br> {$message} <br><br> \n";`

I've tried;

`$text = "ucfirst({$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}) <strong>|</strong> {$timestamp} <br> {$message} <br><br> \n";`

and;

`$text = "ucwords9{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}0 <strong>|</strong> {$timestamp} <br> {$message} <br><br> \n";`

but to no avail. I only want the server username to be shown uppercase.

To echo this works fine with;

`<p>Welcome, <?php echo ucwords ("{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}."); ?>`

You'd get `Welcome, Steve`.

Any ideas for how to post the username with an uppercase first letter would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$text = ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) . "<strong>|</strong> {$timestamp} <br> {$message} <br><br> \n";
```

Comment: Almost works. Space between the username and the `|` is now missing and can't move `"` without it breaking.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a function inside a string like that. PHP will just interpret it as part of the string at best, and potentially as a syntax error. You can `ucfirst` the name before using it in `$text`.

```
$user = ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
$text = "{$user} <strong>|</strong> {$timestamp} <br> {$message} <br><br> \n";
```

You could look into using templates for this kind of thing. They can ease some of the more tedious and error-prone aspects of constructing HTML "by hand" like this.

Comment: Upvoted because that'll be useful, I've managed to fix it with less code, just waiting on an answer edit to be reviewed

Comment: It's cool, less code is good. To be honest the only reason I created another variable like that is so all the code would be visible without scrolling. :-)

Comment: By the way, it's better to just edit the code, the full edit history of the post is visible so you don't need to put "EDIT" or an explanation in the answer text. You should explain the edit in the edit summary. Just FYI, this person may be fine with it, but in general your edits are more likely to be approved if you do that.

Comment: Appreciate it, thank you. Just thought it was worth specifying changes to help aid understanding as to how it works.